# How to retrieve the Primary key right after inserting a new record in Sybase?

Tags: primary-key, sybase

In Sybase how should we get the Primary key right after inserting a new record?
Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you talking about an identity column.

Documentation here: [Retrieving IDENTITY column values with @@identity](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X39476.htm)